# iOS:mobile sim verification code from app

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

i am doing iOS app having a concept of sending verification code to the mobile no from the same mobile  so that it will get verified and give sms back to me. But i need some unique id for that process.Same this kind of process is using by the whats app and other chatting apps.

1)my problem is i am able to send the message to the same mobile no and receiving message from it but i need some unique identification number to the particular mobile. so that if we place sim card in the other mobile the unique identification in may not collide .

Answer (score 0):

As apple has stopped accessing device UDID's programmatically. You can use vendor id as unique identifier. Vendor id is different for same app on different device.

Comment: we have create vendor id programatically

Comment: NSString *strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]; This way you can get vendor id. You can store it on server against phone number for identification of device.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct you are looking for an unique identification for a specific mobile number not for the device. UDID will be different for different devices and vendor id will get changed when the vendor apps are deleted. The only way is to use the mobile number as the identification number.

Comment: VendorID will not be changed on deletion or reinstallation (from appstore)

Answer (score 0):

you can use OpenUDID.

OpenUDID is a drop-in replacement for the deprecated uniqueIdentifier property of the UIDevice class on iOS (a.k.a. UDID) and otherwise is an industry-friendly equivalent for iOS and Android, and most recently Windows C# and Silverlight (see links above).

Here is the link:

https://github.com/xaviermichel/OpenUDID

You app will not be rejected because of OpenUDID. OpenUDID supports from version 5